# Batch Printing Of PDF's with mixed paper source

Tags: pdf, batch, printing, printer

I'm trying to find a way of printing large batches (1000's) of pdf documents.

The first page of each document needs to be on letterhead paper and the rest on regular paper, so mixed input paper / cassettes.

This setting does not appear in the "Printer Properties" dialog but can be accessed in some apps, such as ms word under the "page setup" dialog.

I've tried using a program called "print conductor" found on google and I've also looked at using adobe reader from the command line but there do not seem to be any options to specifiy this.

I would like to use a UI for this but I can write a script or code against a library if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m from company behind Print Conductor and we have another program that will help in this situation.

You can use 2Printer command line tool to print folder with 1000+ PDF files. The idea is in printing 1-st page of each file using paper from one tray and all other pages using paper from different tray.

So, you need to call two command lines you can see below for each file:

```
2Printer.exe -s "C:\In\file01.pdf" -prn "Xerox 2050" -tray "258" -pagerange "1"

2Printer.exe -s "C:\In\file01.pdf" -prn "Xerox 2050" -tray "15" -pagerange "2-999999"
```

You can get list of your printer trays IDs using this command line:

```
2Printer.exe -showtraylist
```

Of course, you need to download and install 2Printer command line tool before from:
https://www.doc2prn.com/download

And here is my batch file example you can try use to print all PDF files from folder "C:\In":

```
FOR %%i IN (C:\In\*.pdf) DO (

2Printer.exe -s "%%i" -prn "Xerox 2050" -tray "258" -pagerange "1"

2Printer.exe -s "%%i" -prn "Xerox 2050" -tray "15" -pagerange "2-999999"

)
```

If you need further help setting it up - you can ask me here or via support from our our website.

Comment: works well until you run out of paper in one of the trays.

Answer (score 0):

When printing PDF files with mixed page sizes to a dual tray printer,
it is possible for some applications to specify the print option of
*Choose paper source by PDF page size*.

Any not too old version of Adobe Acrobat supports this option:

[image]

Foxit Reader also supports it:

[image]

For any other PDF product look for that option.
It can also be found as option in some printer software.

Comment: Thanks for answering but I'm not sure how that helps me?  I need to print 1000s of pdfs and the paper size doesn't vary.  To use those options from a batch job i would need to specify then from command line?

Comment: That depends on which tool you are using for printing. But if the paper size doesn't vary, then the only idea I have is to cut up each PDF file into two PDF files and printing two batches with matching tray option.

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways of getting what you want: either the application sends different pages to different trays, or the printer does it itself.

As you said, applications like Word let you specify a different tray for the first page, but most other app do not. I do not know of any PDF reader that does.

The other option is to tell the printer. In that case it will be a selection somewhere under printer Printing Preferences and/or Printing Defaults. Many high-end printers support this option, but it is sometimes hard to find. In your case, you say it's not supported, but try clicking all the tabs and buttons in Preferences.

What model is the printer?